# Where is layout/generic in mozilla?

Tags: firefox, mozilla

On Ubuntu I can't find mozilla's layout/generic/...

Ref: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/generic

Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about the source code of Firefox.

If you have Firefox installed on Ubuntu, you will not get its source code but the binaries compiled from it on your computer, hence you will not be able to find the `layout/generic/` folder.

To inspect the source code your version of Firefox was built from, run

```
apt source firefox
```

and `apt` will download a source archive file for you. Beware that in the case of Firefox, this archive is about 250 MB in size. You also have to have the sources repositories enabled in your Software & Updates settings, not only the standard binary repositories.

Alternatively you can download the source archives from Launchpad from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox .